# Why does Map's + operator need double parentheses?

Tags: scala

For example:

```
val m = Map[Int, Int]()
m + (1, 1) // doesn't work!
m + ((1, 1)) // works!
```

I know `(1, 1)` is a `Tuple2`, but then why doesn't the former work? Can I avoid this quirky double parentheses?

Comment: BTW: there has been talk about unifying tuples and argument lists, but that never went anywhere, for various reasons: backwards compatibility is a nightmare, platform compatibility (i.e. compatibility with Java or C#) is near impossible, and it's not a big ticket feature anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m + (1, 1)` is the same thing as `m.+(1, 1)`, that is, it's a function call with two integer arguments rather than a call with a single Tuple2 argument.

You can however use `->` which forms a Tuple without parentheses thus:

```
val m = Map[Int, Int]()
m + 1 -> 1 // works!
```

or perhaps more usefully:

```
var m = Map[Int, Int]()
m += 1 -> 1 // works!
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script doesn't work because you try to use method that doesn't exist. In your case Scala thinks that you want to use function [`+`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.Map@+[B1%3E:B](kv:(A,B1)):scala.collection.mutable.Map[A,B1]) with two arguments (`Int` and `Int`) instead of one (`Tuple2`).

The best way to solve the problem it is use `->` operator. Here is example code:

```
scala> val m = Map[Int, Int]()
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map() 
scala> m + (1 -> 1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

Comment: Please, add explanations.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `m + (1, 1)` Scala thinks that you want to call method `+` with 2 arguments, i.e. `m.+(1, 1)`, and fails because such method does not exist.

You could write it in such a way when compiler has no doubts regarding number of passed arguments:

As mentioned before:

`m + (1 -> 1)`

or

`val m = Map[Int, Int]()
val t = (1, 1)
m + t`